# post or get for controller actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post, http-get

I am working with asp.net mvc 4.0 and doing alot of client side development.

I have a general question regarding using POST or GETS when interacting with the server for jquery calls.

Is it more perform ant to use a GET and not a POST when lets say adding items to a database via  controller action?

Answer (score 2):

There is no appreciable *performance* difference between GET and POST, but there are very important *functional* differences. One key difference is that GETs are for idempotent requests and POSTs are for submitting changes. GET requests should thus always be safe to repeat, but for a POST there is a risk that an action will be taken that affects state and cannot be repeated without further affecting state.

Another common concern is that by allowing GETs the application is at risk of having certain web site crawlers and optimizers invoke all the GETs and cause server changes (such as deleting all the entities in the site - this is no joke, it happens in real sites all the time).

Whether the request comes in through AJAX or not is also not a factor in terms of performance or functionality.